# Data processing on spark using java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

I have a DataSet.

```
+-------------------+
|     Date          |
+-------------------+
|1970-01-01 06:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

I want to take only the hour and the minute.The column Date is on timestamp.
I tried the following code :

```
       String format = "HH:mm";
       df.withColumn("hour:minute",unix_timestamp(col("Date"),format)).show(100);
```

But doesn't work for me .

Thank you .

Comment: I think you want to use [`from_unixtime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and not `unix_timestamp()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`unix_timestamp`** converts timestamp to **epoch/unix time**.

- Use either **`date_format`**,**`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`** functions to extract `hour:minute`.

Example:

```
df.withColumn("hour:minute",date_format(col("Date"),"HH:mm")).show()
df.withColumn("hour:minute",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("Date"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),"HH:mm")).show()

//+-------------------+-----------+
//|               Date|hour:minute|
//+-------------------+-----------+
//|1970-01-01 06:00:00|      06:00|
//+-------------------+-----------+
```